# integer and string to char (same value) java

Tags: java, input, char, int

I think my Problem is not that hard, but I´m a beginner so it is hard for me.
I have to read Keyboard Inputs (Numbers < and > 256 and characters) and put all of that into an char[].

```
Example:

Input
120
1101
AU
1050
```

---

```
Output
char[0] = 0
char[1] = 120

char[2] = 4
char[3] = 77  ((4*256)+77 = 1101)

char[4] = A
char[5] = U

char[6] = 4
char[7] = 26  ((4*256)+26 = 1050)
```

The Problem is if i use scanner it and convert it to int it will give me 49 instead of 1101.
If i use BufferedReader i cant convert str into int.

I hope someone can help me with this. 
Thx

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: Your requirements aren't quite clear.  It looks like if the next thing in the input looks like an integer, then you treat it as an integer, otherwise you treat it as characters?  Perhaps [`Scanner.hasNextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--) would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok thanks for any help. I found out how it works for me.

```
`int u = scann.nextInt();

            int c = u/256;
            int wieder = (u-(256*c));
            outtel[2] = (char) c;
            outtel[3] = (char) wieder;`
```

Just an exampe but i just had to cast the integer to char.